# Check if date is a recurrence of another day

Tags: date, go, math

How can i check if a date is a biweekly(every two weeks) recurrence of another?
For instance for the initial date 13/01/2022, how can i check if the date 31/03/2022 is a biweekly recurrence of the initial date?

Comment: simple math: check if the distance is a multiple of 14 days

Comment: Do you want to check if its exactly 2 weeks to the nanosecond. or just the same day?  If the same day local time or UTC?

Comment: if a = b mod c then a-b = 0 mod c. Convert the dates to days, subtract them, and check if the difference equals 0 mod 14.

Answer (score 1):

The `SameDay` function checks if two times fall on the same day of a time period. Use an interval of 14 for biweekly. (This assumes a "day" in local time but you can change `time.Local` to be UTC or any timezone.)  Note that 86400 is seconds in a day.

```
import (
    "time"
)

const (
  SecondsPerDay = 24*60*60
)

func main() {
    println(SameDay(14, time.Now(), time.Now().Add(time.Hour*24*14)))
    println(SameDay(14, time.Now(), time.Now().Add(time.Hour*24*15)))
}

// StartOfDay finds time of start of day in local time zone
func StartOfDay(t time.Time) time.Time {
    return time.Date(t.Year(), t.Month(), t.Day(), 0, 0, 0, 0, time.Local)
}

// SameDay returns true if times fall on the same day of an interval
// interval = the time interval in days
// t1, t2 = the two times
func SameDay(interval int, t1, t2 time.Time) bool {
    return (StartOfDay(t1).Unix()/SecondsPerDay)%interval == (StartOfDay(t2).Unix()/SecondsPerDay)%interval
}
```

[Try it on the Go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/1jE1aA-RLYi)

Comment: It works :D 
Could you please explain-me why divide the dates by the number of seconds in a day?

Comment: Hi @bimsi, glad it works (please select as the answer).   `why divide the dates by the number of seconds in a day` - this is because the `time.Time.Unix()` method returns a time in seconds (from 1/1/1970).  We need to work with days.  BTW I have updated the function to be more generally useful (taking an interval parameter) but in you case you just use 14.

Answer (score 0):

another approach,

```
func isBiWeekly(t1, t2 time.Time) bool {
    t1 = t1.Truncate(time.Hour)
    t2 = t2.Truncate(time.Hour)
    return int(t2.Sub(t1).Hours()/24)%14 == 0
}
```

full version : https://go.dev/play/p/da3Gliztb2B

Comment: Cool idea to use time.Time.`Truncate` but this will use UTC days (which is maybe what the OP wanted).   Also because you subtract the hours **before** dividing by 24 this will have issues where times are near midnight (which may be OK for the OP).

Comment: if t1 & t2 are same timezone, Truncate is worked fine.
if want more precise, it can truncate to hour (not day).

Comment: it does not matter what timezone t1 and t2 are using when you truncate you are getting the day in which the time falls in in UTC.  If both times have the same time of day then it's OK, but if not then you need to adjust for the timezone offset before truncating.  Sorry if I have not explained this well. Also my 2nd point still stands - try the maths with some real times (I have).

Comment: thnaks for your advise, i have study Truncate's source code. It count from zero time. so, i truncate it by hour. actually, i like readable code.